# Can I snap an objects so their edges line up?

Tags: snapping

I want to make the cube snap precisely to the corner of the plane, so it looks like this image:

[image: setup]
(This was done manually and is not a precise snap, just an idea of what I want to accomplish)

I'm using the plane as a sort of "foundation," then building on top of it with cubes. I want to be able to snap a cube to each corner.

Blender's snapping mechanism has given me trouble in the past, and I want to know what the best way to do this is.

Comment: Have you studied Neil Hirsig's [video tutorial](https://vimeo.com/44841971) on snapping and aligning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I not sure what problems you have had in the past with blenders snapping in the past but I'd personal use the snapping options here as I believe it'd be the fastest and most simple way to get it done. I apologize in advance if you were tying to avoid the snap tool completely for some reason.

My solution:

Set the snap element to vertex, by using the button next to the snap button on the 3D views header bar **OR** press **ctrl+shift+tab** to bring the snapping options menu up by it's shortcut.

[image: snap Element menu]

Select the cube. Press **G** to enter grab/move mode. Hold **ctrl** down and point the plains lower right vertex and click to confirm the move.

[image]

If it all went right the cube should be perfectly aligned to the corner. If you duplicate it then hold ctrl and point to another corner it should make a new copy and snap it to whatever corner you point to.

**Note on How snapping works in blender:**

When snapping two elements together blender will try and snap the closets points together, from where The moved object starts.

So if your cube is above and to the left of the vertex you are trying to snap to, The cubes bottom right vertex will be the closest point and that will be the part that snaps into position.

*I hope I've explained this all clearly and that it helps you out! good luck!*

Answer (score 1):

Consider Align Objects ... Space .... align

[image]

Prior to Align Objects. Both objects centered on origin. Both Selected. Plane active object.

[image]